# Conditional css on hover based on class of row of Vuetify simple table

Tags: css, vue.js, hover, vuetify.js, tablerow

I have a Vuetify `v-simple-table` where I need to render row css differently depending on whether a task is complete or not.

I can conditionally render the background color with the following code.

```html
<tr :class="[done? 'greenBG' : 'whiteBG']">
```

The css is straight forward.

```
  .greenBG {
    background-color: #79ecc5;
  }
  .whiteBG {
    background-color: white;
  }
```

However, I cannot seem to disable the defualt `:hover` css. I tried connecting it to the class with this css.

```
  tr.greenBG:hover { background-color: green }
```

If anyone can help me achieve this I'd be grateful.

Comment: Check your use of `tr.greenBG:hover { background-color: green } ` sometimes browsers like to have that semi-colon `tr.greenBG:hover { background-color: green; } ` OR just add to the specificity of the selector `.v-data-table__wrapper tr.greenBG:hover { background-color: green; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the [`!important` property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) to ensure you override any conflicting vuetify CSS

```css
tr.greenBG:hover { 
  background-color: green !important
}
```

if you really want to avoid using `!important` you need to be as specific as [vuetify's CSS selector](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/8bb752b210d25fbebcea12cd073d2ce4986f5e12/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/VSimpleTable.sass#L28):

```css
.v-data-table__wrapper
  table
  tbody
  tr.greenBG:hover:not(.v-data-table__expanded__content):not(.v-data-table__empty-wrapper) {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to double-check that it's mandatory tho (using your browser's devtools), the usage of `!important` may be overkill.

Comment: Thanks. Worked a charm. I'd forgotten about `!important`.

Comment: Most times when you add `!important` to CSS that means something else is wrong (unless you are writing a reusable library) like too much CSS or the cascade is misunderstood etc.

Comment: Vuetify CSS itself sometimes uses `!important` so sometimes it's a necessary evil. I looked deeper and in this instance it can be avoided so the answer has been modified to include an alternative.